# Word To Describe The Repetitive Sound Of A Television In The Background

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word to describe the sound of a television in the background that the character has tuned out. The sentence I'm trying to put it in is 
"The television [Insert word here] in the background as..."

Comment: Perhaps **murmur**?

Comment: Or **chattering** (or **nattering**).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## White noise

Although *technically* '**noise containing many frequencies with equal intensities**,' it can also mean:

> 1. A constant background noise; especially :  one that drowns out other sounds
> 2. Meaningless or distracting commotion, hubbub, or chatter

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/white%20noise)

Either of which could suit your case, e.g.:

> The television's white noise in the background was..."

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: @R.R happy to help!

Comment: There is a serious flaw somewhere. This isn't the verb OP requests, but is the answer they seek.

Comment: "The television _white noised_ in the background as..."?

Comment: I changed the sentence to fix it up as I couldn't find a verb that conveyed the intended meaning. I apologize for that. I'll edit the original post so it makes more sense